# Cocoa - controlTextDidEndEditing issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have the following delegate method which is listening for when text changes in an editable field:

-(void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification{

Say, I have two NSTextFields declared, how can I find out which is the NSTextField that generated the notification? I want to perform some code when one text field's text did finish editing and other code when the other text field's code finishes editing.

In other words, how can I get the name of the text field that gave the notification?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[aNotification object] is the NSControl (or NSControl subclass) object which posted the notification.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives, for example:

<NSTextField: 0x10013b7d0>. 

Is there a way to get the actual name that I gave it in the IBOutlet decleration?

Comment: Ok solved, not exactly the name but I guess that is not really possible..

I did:


 if ([aNotification object] == tf)

with tf being the NSTextField I declared in the IBOutlet. If that returned true then I know that it was the textfield called tf that generated the notification. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use tags and get the tag field of the object, but first you have to force downcast the object from Any to NSTextField so you can access the tag property (an object of "any" doesn't have a "tag" property) like so:

```
let object = aNotification.object as! NSTextField
```

then you can check the tag:

```
if object.tag == 99 { do something }
```

That's how I addressed the issue in some of the code I'm working on now.